# CMake: how to specify from command line where to look for locally installed libraries

Tags: c, cmake, makefile, dependencies, configure

I am building locally a dependencies and installing in a local directory. Now I would like to tell CMake to look into that local directory for include and libraries, in addition to all the standard places.

I tried this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=`realpath ../target`/lib CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=`realpath ../target`/include .
```

But it did not work. Any idea?

Comment: You need to prefix `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=...` with -D as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
find_library()
```

command to search for libraries.

With

```
include_directories()
```

you tell cmake where to look for include files

Comment: But that would mean to change the CMake files of the project I want to compile. I am not trying to do that, I would like to specify as a parameter to CMake the directory where I have installed the dependencies it is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can first add the folder to your PC's system environment, e.g. called `PersonalLib_DIR` that points to the folder. Then you can add it for include and libraries by accessing `$ENV{PersonalLib_DIR}` via CMake:

1. For include:

   ```
   include_directories($ENV{PersonalLib_DIR})
   ```
2. For libraries (assume you want to link the `aLib.lib` under the folder):

   ```
   target_link_libraries(youProject $ENV{PersonalLib_DIR}/aLib)
   ```

Comment: Yes but again it would mean changing the CMakeLists.txt file of the project I am using. I would like to avoid that if possible. I am looking for standard ways to specify additional dirs to search into for libs